# Google Analytics Event Tracking not recording numeric label values

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

It looks like Google Analytics cannot track events with numeric values in the label.

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', '12345']);
```

Is it possible that GA can't record numeric values? I can't find anything in the GA docs.

At the same time I also use Universal Analytics with the same event. But in Universal Analytics the numeric label is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

The label is always a string. If you omit the label (since it is optional) and put in an integer, then that parameter would be considered the "value" of the event.

[sources: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq, http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/event-tracking-explained]

Comment: Event value would go into ROI calculations, so this is not necessarily what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the label (for the same event) is not always numeric.

The values looks like:
12345
T12345

The string with 'T12345' is recorded by GA, but 12345 not.